# iis 7 + http custom handler error: could not load file or assembly The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#-4.0, iis-7, httphandler, filenotfoundexception

Windows vista 32 bit - C# - .NET 4 - sqlite - IIS 7

I'm building a small project that contains is a custom HTTP handler where an user can request  a XML file and the project will generate the file and send it to the user. It should be flexible enough to send something else too like e.g. json.

Everything was going well until I had to deploy the handler. I've created a library (dll) file which contains the logic for serving of the requested information. I've open IIS manager and I've created a virtual directory to the debug bin file (later on i made it an application. it did not make a difference).

I've followed countless examples and tutorials like these ones:

I started with this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx

But with no luck. As you could have read I'm not using any asp.net website even though I do have a **web.config** that I've added to the bin folder and it looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script, Execute">
      <add name="LigoManagedHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="Ligo.Service, Ligo" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I try to run handler in the browser get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Ligo' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 


Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Ligo' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried so many possible combination in IIS manager to get it working ('httphandlers', 'classic mode' and so on ...) but i'm truly stuck. The information I've found on the internet is not helping much.

**What am I doing wrong or missing to make it work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. I had to make a asp.net website project and add my dll as reference to this project.

I read this thread that provided this information which is not clear on the internet.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1088861.aspx/1?What+causes+the+quot+Could+not+load+type+quot+problem+

It should state that it is not possible to make the httphandler without a aspnet website project. or am i mistaken? the example on the internet are incorrect! or provide too little information.

Answer (score 4):

Something in this rant triggered an idea, an I stumbled on the answer.

The line in all those tutorials that say put `type="ClassName, AssemblyName"` into the Handlers section in Web.Config are plain WRONG.

All I did was change this to `type="AssemblyName.ClassName"` and everything started working, in both a Web Site Project and a Web Application Project that I had created.

I'm running IIS 7.5 in integrated mode so YMMV.

Craig

Comment: @Mihai Code formatting is for code, not to emphasize random phrases. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116741/175647

Comment: Oh, my God, you are so right! Without your post it would take forever to make it working...

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is an old thread. However, I've been looking for an answer for a few days without finding a clear one. So, in case anyone comes across similar scenario.

You can create custom Http Handler as a stand-alone Class Library project and use it in IIS.

On IIS Add new Application with ASP4 Integrated mode. Place your compiled DLL into **bin** folder (this is what i was missing all along). Seems obvious that it should be there; took some time to figure this out. :)

web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.ogg" name="test" type="Namespace.Classname"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.